# Magic the Gathering for very young kids

Tags: magic-the-gathering, house-rules, kids

I have a ton of MTG cards sitting around and an urge to use them again.  I also have a 4 year old son.

I'm sure he won't appreciate my B/G infect deck or the rules of the game in general lol.

I'm trying to think of ways to use my stockpile for games with him.  So far the only thing I can come up with is to cut down deck sizes to 15-20 all monster cards with equal power\toughness.  So a bunch of 1/1-4/4's and we can run monsters into each other to let him figure out which numbers are bigger.

The post [here](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/29074/ways-to-handicap-in-magic-the-gathering) is kind of related but it's focused on older kids that can read and do real math already.

Can anyone else think of something fun to do with a megaton of old MTG cards for pre-school age kids?

EDIT:  And to clarify, I'm looking for non-destructive ideas.  I'm positive I'm going to get a few bent corners in this process but no glue\scissor projects please!  lol

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have to vote to close this as a game recommendation question. You're asking for fun games to play with a particular kind of game piece, just like someone might ask for fun playing card games or dice games.

Comment: It's about augmenting the idea of the original game into something that a 4 year old can handle.

Is there a better outlet for this kind of question?

Comment: I see your point, but the game you describe (a deck with only creature cards, creatures fighting each other) removes almost all of the existing elements of Magic. Unfortunately, I don't know a better place to ask something like this. Perhaps the [Magic subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/magictcg).

Comment: The closest question I can figure out that would nearly be answerable would be "How young should I attempt to start my children on MTG" but event that is purely subjective. Personally I think you should hold off on MTG until they are old enough to tackle it all. If you must, play some version of snap.

Comment: I started playing with my dad in kindergarten. We would mainly play mono color decks and starter decks. I would play with my hand facing up so my dad could help me and in a year or so I was able to play by myself (although still not well). I liked playing like this, and as long as you don't mind play against yourself I would suggest it.